# Unexpected output when trying to return key with largest value in LinkedHashMap java

Tags: java, hashmap, linkedhashmap

Im trying to return the key with largest value in LinkedHashMap,

```
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;

public class stuff {
LinkedHashMap<Integer, Integer> hashMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
static int maxKey;

  public void createHashmap() {
      hashMap.put(0,0);
      hashMap.put(2,3);
      }

    
  public int getHighestKey() {
      Integer maxKey = null;
      for (Integer key : hashMap.keySet()) {
          if (maxKey == null || hashMap.get(key) > hashMap.get(maxKey)) {
              maxKey = key;
          }
      }
      return maxKey;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
      System.out.println(maxKey);
    
  }
}
```

The output I get when I run this code is 0, even though in theory it should be 2. Why is this happening and how do I fix it.

Comment: `int` in java is a primitive type with a default value of 0. You never called any of the functions, so the value never changed.

Comment: I called the functions in the main method and changed all data structures and variables to static and I am still getting 0, if I change maxKey to Integer I get "null" returned instead. What changes do I need to make to get it to work as intended?

Comment: And even if you would call your methods, your method `getHighestKey` returns the value and only temporarily sets `Integer maxKey` which is a local variable and not your `static int maxKey` that you print. I would recommend deleting the `static int maxKey` field as you do not need it. Instead create an object of you class and call your methods and print the return value of your `getHighestKey()` call.

Answer (score 2):

You're comparing the map's *values* for the keys, not the keys themselves.

Change:

```
for (Integer key : hashMap.keySet()) {
    if (maxKey == null || hashMap.get(key) > hashMap.get(maxKey)) {
        maxKey = key;
    }
}
```

To

```
for (Integer key : hashMap.keySet()) {
    if (maxKey == null || key > maxKey) {
        maxKey = key;
    }
}
```

---

Rather than write your own code, you could have just done this:

```
Integer maxKey = Collections.max(hashMap.keySet());
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is yet another way.

- first, check if the map exists and has values.  Otherwise throw an exception since returing any default `int` could be misleading.
- then just iterate over the keys, comparing current value to max.

```
 public int getHighestKey() {
     if(hashMap == null || hashMap.size() == 0) {
         throw new IllegalArgumentException("Map is null or empty");
     }
     int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
     for (int i : hashMap.keySet()) {
         max = Math.max(max, i);
     }
     return max;    
    }
}
```

Unless a `LinkedHashMap` is required, you could use a [TreeMap](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/util/TreeMap.html#TreeMap()) which maintains the keys in a sorted order (ascending by default).

```
NavigableMap<Integer,Integer> map = new TreeMap<>();
map.put(7,8);
map.put(4,2);
map.put(5,2);

int maxKey = map.lastKey();
System.out.println(maxKey);
```

prints

```
7
```